# No backend menu in odoo 9

Tags: odoo

When working with Optimize SEO for the website I have constructed in Odoo 9, I declared a keyword that seems to be too long, or something is wrong with it because I don't have the option to removed it (delete it) from the list of keywords.

All Odoo got blocked after declaring that keyword, and now I cannot see my menu in odoo, only the website.

I tried to backup the data base, but the command is not executed, it just returns to the same page, without doing anything.
The errors I've got can find out enclosed picture.

Hope someone came across this kind of issue and can help me with some tips.

Thank you in advance!
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c5D4H.png)

Answer (score 0):

As par my opinion menu will not display because of all CSS will not Loaded properly. You can may be solved it by delete all attachments if is has not that much important.

First of restore database in new database and perform following query in database.

```
delete from ir_attachment;
```

I hope this will work for you.

Thanks.